# Break when the latter digit is greater than the previous digit in haskell

Tags: haskell, split

I'm writing a function which uses `break` in Haskell. This function will break the string list when the latter character is greater than the previous one. For example: "176" would return ("1","76"), "1276" would return ("12","76"). However my function works fine with "1276", but when the input is "176" it only returns ("176",""). My function is as follows. Can someone please help me find out why? Thank you.

```
myBreak (x:y:xs) = break (\x -> x > y ) (x:y:xs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you compare each character in the input string with that string's *second* character, `y`, always, instead of comparing it to the previous one in the string. The `y` comes from the pattern you're using,

```
myBreak (x:y:xs) = break (\x -> x > y ) (x:y:xs)
            \               \__/   /
             \____________________/
```

So when the input is `"176"`, its second character is `'7'`, and there's *no* character greater than `'7'` in the input string, so it doesn't stop till the end.

This answers this question.

So your function isn't actually doing what you wanted it to do. But that's another question, how to code this function correctly, which was already asked here on SO many times, I think.

---

(misread your question)

Because that's how the built-in function [`break`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=break) is defined to work.

Its type is

```
break :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
```

You supply it with the predicate `(\x -> x > y )` and the input list `(x:y:xs)`, and it returns you a pair of lists in a tuple, [as advertised](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:break):

> `break`, applied to a predicate `p` and a list `xs`, returns a tuple where first element is longest prefix (possibly empty) of `xs` of elements that *do not satisfy* `p` and second element is the remainder of the list

and in your last case the remainder is an empty list of `Char`s, i.e. the empty string `""`.

The pattern `(x:y:xs)` that you're using demands the input list have at least 2 elements in it. Since you don't specify any additional equations for the function it will fail with an error if called with shorter strings. You can just use `xs` instead.

Comment: Thank you, but my function `(\x -> x > y)` works. And when I input "1276", it returns the result ("12","76") which is what I want. But when I input "176", I want it to return ("1","76") but it returns ("176","") instead

Comment: my bad, wasn't thinking straight for a moment or two.

Comment: of course that means that you compare each character in the input string with that string's *second* character, always, instead of comparing it to the previous one in the string. but that's another question, how to code this function correctly. if you want to ask it, please do so in another post, don't change this question. btw that question has already been asked many times, do a search before you post. maybe I'll find something and give you links here later.